# Haskell - Instance Declaration on hMatrix

Tags: haskell, hmatrix

I'm using the function `fromBlocks` from hMatrix over a list whose elements are determined by functions of type `Int -> Int -> Int -> Matrix Int`. However, GHC complains saying that:

```
No instance for (Element Int) arising from a use of `fromBlocks'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Element Int)
    In the expression:
      fromBlocks [[matrixCreate n m d], [rowZero n m d]]
```

I tried to tell GHC the type of the result of this computation with `:: Matrix Int` but it didn't work, and I don't understand how to declare the type when using the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - there is really no instance for `Element Int` - see here: [http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.16.0.3/docs/Numeric-LinearAlgebra-HMatrix.html#t:Element](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.16.0.3/docs/Numeric-LinearAlgebra-HMatrix.html#t%3aElement)

Just go for `Matrix Float` or `Matrix Double` if you can

Comment: Alberto (the package author) agrees with vivian that this answer is incorrect.

Comment: Then maybe give a hint whats wrong and we can fix it - oh wait you just want to push your own answer...

Answer (score 0):

Just declare an `instance Element Int` as described in [1].  Be warned that many of the fancier functions are only defined for `Double` and `Float`.

[1] https://github.com/albertoruiz/hmatrix/issues/28

**Edit**: add Alberto's comment:

```
instance Element Int

a = (2><3) [1..] :: Matrix Int

z = (1><1) [0] :: Matrix Int

m = fromBlocks [[a,z],[a,a]]

> m

(4><6)
 [ 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0
 , 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0
 , 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3
 , 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Comment: That's correct. You can do something like this:

    instance Element Int

    a = (2><3) [1..] :: Matrix Int

    z = (1><1) [0] :: Matrix Int

    m = fromBlocks [[a,z],[a,a]]

> m

    (4><6)
     [ 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0
     , 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0
     , 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3
     , 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6 ]

But there are very few useful operations for Int elements.